# How to know which .war file does "eb deploy" deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am a novice to AWS, and I want to deploy a web-application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I did some online research, and found that we have to do the following:

`1) eb init` <-- It does initialization
`2) en deploy` <-- It deploys to AWS Elastic beanstalk.

Does it deploy the .war automatically? And If a project has multiple .war would it deploy all the .war's?

The eb deploy doesn't say anything, all it outputs that deployed successfully.

Any help to understand highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eb deploy` works in a way that it takes the current git repository, zips it, uploads it to the server and deploys it there. So there's no need to create a WAR file at all. You can simply issue `eb deploy` from the local web folder. Just make sure it has the proper structure (e.g. WEB-INF folder etc).

For reference, [here's an old script](https://github.com/ayush/eb-deploy) that probably doesn't work, but aims to deploy a WAR to beanstalk. Check out how it unzips the war and issues `git aws.push` (the equivalent to `eb deploy`).

If you'd like to use WAR you can upload it manually via the online web console or unzip it and then use `eb deploy`

Comment: Thanks for your comments; so if i have created a web-application and created a war file (in target directory), how can i specify how to deploy that specific .war file? I saw lot online resources, however, not able to get what i am looking for.

Comment: why do you want to deploy the war when you can deploy the git sources? let beanstalk do it for you. AFAIK you can only upload the WAR manually via the web console

Comment: It is some needs based on which I have this need. So does it mean we can't manually upload particular .war using eb deploy? Is there any other mechanism (maven plugin)?

Comment: nope. in order to upload a particular war you'll need to unzip it, add it to local git, and eb deploy from that folder. not too bad, but totally awkward. Here's an old script that did it (using `git aws.push` rather than `eb deploy`)

Comment: Is it necessary to add to local git? I know my basics aren't clear right now, but why do we need to add a .war to repository just for deployment? Isn't AWS's purpose to make this a simple task? I searched a lot of materials online and still same doubt. BTW, which scripts you were referring to? Appreciate your help.

Comment: added some explanation to the answer body

Comment: To clarify, it is possible to override the default behavior and specify a specific WAR file in .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

...
deploy:
  artifact: target/my.war
...